# how to increase layout RtlViewPager

Tags: java, android

I don't know how to increase the size  RtlViewPager Only half of the image given below is working for me in the viewpage test. How to bring this full  [image: i need data]  show only half screen data why [image: image2] dontshow fu screen data how togetfullscreen data I am given the image below but only half of the screen is shown to me

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/calendartoday"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_width="376dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="TextView4" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
        <LinearLayout
                       android:id="@+id/lyt_fragment_header"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:orientation="vertical"
                       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                       android:paddingTop="10dp"
                       android:paddingRight="10dp">
    
                       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
                           <com.Tamiltv.newspaper.utils.RtlViewPager
                               android:id="@+id/fragment_header"
                               android:layout_width="0dp"
                               android:layout_height="0dp"
                               android:clipToPadding="false"
                               android:overScrollMode="never"
                               app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1.2"
                               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    
    
                   </LinearLayout>
    
    
    
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_featured"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager_featured"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1.2"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
            <LinearLayout
    
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabDots"
                    android:background="@color/card_background_color"
    
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
            </LinearLayout>
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <Spinner
    
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="132dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
            <Spinner
    
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="132dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
            <Spinner
    
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_width="132dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <Button
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:text="submit" />
    
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/prev"
    
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                android:text="Prev"
                app:icon="@drawable/prev"
                app:iconGravity="start"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck">
    
            </Button>
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/today"
                app:icon="@drawable/today"
                app:iconGravity="start"
    
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                android:text="Today">
    
            </Button>
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                android:text="Next"
                app:icon="@drawable/next"
                app:iconGravity="start"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck">
    
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <!--    <LinearLayout-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/lyt_category2"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="vertical">-->
    
    <!--        <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout-->
    <!--            android:id="@+id/ripple_more_category2"-->
    <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleHover="true"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"/>-->
    
    <!--        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView-->
    <!--            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_category2"-->
    <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"-->
    <!--            android:scrollbars="none"-->
    <!--            android:scrollingCache="true" />-->
    
    <!--    </LinearLayout>-->
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <!--    <LinearLayout-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/lyt_category3"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="vertical">-->
    
    <!--        <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout-->
    <!--            android:id="@+id/ripple_more_category3"-->
    <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleHover="true"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">-->
    
    <!--            <RelativeLayout-->
    <!--                android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--                android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                android:gravity="center_vertical"-->
    <!--                android:orientation="horizontal"-->
    <!--                android:padding="10dp">-->
    
    <!--                <LinearLayout-->
    <!--                    android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/arrow_more3"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_more3"-->
    <!--                    android:orientation="vertical">-->
    
    <!--                    <TextView-->
    <!--                        android:id="@+id/txt_title_category3"-->
    <!--                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                        android:text=""-->
    <!--                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"-->
    <!--                        android:textSize="18sp"-->
    <!--                        android:textStyle="bold" />-->
    
    <!--                </LinearLayout>-->
    
    <!--                <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout-->
    <!--                    android:id="@+id/arrow_more3"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"-->
    <!--                    app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"-->
    <!--                    app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"-->
    <!--                    app:mrl_rippleHover="true"-->
    <!--                    app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">-->
    
    <!--                    <ImageView-->
    <!--                        android:id="@+id/img_arrow_category3"-->
    <!--                        android:layout_width="24dp"-->
    <!--                        android:layout_height="24dp" />-->
    
    <!--                </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>-->
    
    <!--            </RelativeLayout>-->
    
    <!--        </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>-->
    
    <!--        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView-->
    <!--            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_category3"-->
    <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"-->
    <!--            android:scrollbars="none"-->
    <!--            android:scrollingCache="true" />-->
    
    <!--    </LinearLayout>-->
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                android:id="@+id/ripple_more_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp">
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/arrow_more"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_more"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
    
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_title_category"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    </LinearLayout>
    
                    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                        android:id="@+id/arrow_more"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                        app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_arrow_category"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" />
    
                    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
                </RelativeLayout>
    
            </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:scrollingCache="true" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <com.solodroid.ads.sdk.ui.MediumNativeAdView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_recipes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                android:id="@+id/ripple_recent_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp">
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/arrow_recent_more"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_recent_more"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
    
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_title_recent"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    </LinearLayout>
    
                    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                        android:id="@+id/arrow_recent_more"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                        app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_arrow_recent"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" />
    
                    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
                </RelativeLayout>
    
            </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_recent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:scrollingCache="true" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_videos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                android:id="@+id/ripple_videos_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp">
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/arrow_videos_more"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_videos_more"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
    
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_title_videos"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    </LinearLayout>
    
                    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                        android:id="@+id/arrow_videos_more"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                        app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_arrow_videos"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" />
    
                    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
                </RelativeLayout>
    
            </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_videos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:scrollingCache="true" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
    </LinearLayout>


how to clear viewpager size
```

Answer (score 0):

set the layout_height from wrap_content to match_parent

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: not show full screen coding update check bro

Comment: totel 8 text only show 3 text viewpager why bro

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/calendartoday"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_width="376dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="TextView4" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
        <LinearLayout
                       android:id="@+id/lyt_fragment_header"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:orientation="vertical"
                       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                       android:paddingTop="10dp"
                       android:paddingRight="10dp">
    
                       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                           <com.Tamiltv.newspaper.utils.RtlViewPager
                               android:id="@+id/fragment_header"
                               android:layout_width="0dp"
                               android:layout_height="0dp"
                               android:clipToPadding="false"
                               android:overScrollMode="never"
                               app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1.2"
                               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    
    
                   </LinearLayout>
    
    
    
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_featured"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager_featured"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1.2"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    
            <LinearLayout
    
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabDots"
                    android:background="@color/card_background_color"
    
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
            </LinearLayout>
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <Spinner
    
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="132dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
            <Spinner
    
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="132dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
            <Spinner
    
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_width="132dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <Button
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:text="submit" />
    
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/prev"
    
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                android:text="Prev"
                app:icon="@drawable/prev"
                app:iconGravity="start"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck">
    
            </Button>
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/today"
                app:icon="@drawable/today"
                app:iconGravity="start"
    
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                android:text="Today">
    
            </Button>
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                android:text="Next"
                app:icon="@drawable/next"
                app:iconGravity="start"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck">
    
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <!--    <LinearLayout-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/lyt_category2"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="vertical">-->
    
    <!--        <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout-->
    <!--            android:id="@+id/ripple_more_category2"-->
    <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleHover="true"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"/>-->
    
    <!--        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView-->
    <!--            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_category2"-->
    <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"-->
    <!--            android:scrollbars="none"-->
    <!--            android:scrollingCache="true" />-->
    
    <!--    </LinearLayout>-->
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <!--    <LinearLayout-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/lyt_category3"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"-->
    <!--        android:orientation="vertical">-->
    
    <!--        <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout-->
    <!--            android:id="@+id/ripple_more_category3"-->
    <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleHover="true"-->
    <!--            app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">-->
    
    <!--            <RelativeLayout-->
    <!--                android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--                android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                android:gravity="center_vertical"-->
    <!--                android:orientation="horizontal"-->
    <!--                android:padding="10dp">-->
    
    <!--                <LinearLayout-->
    <!--                    android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/arrow_more3"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_more3"-->
    <!--                    android:orientation="vertical">-->
    
    <!--                    <TextView-->
    <!--                        android:id="@+id/txt_title_category3"-->
    <!--                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                        android:text=""-->
    <!--                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"-->
    <!--                        android:textSize="18sp"-->
    <!--                        android:textStyle="bold" />-->
    
    <!--                </LinearLayout>-->
    
    <!--                <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout-->
    <!--                    android:id="@+id/arrow_more3"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
    <!--                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"-->
    <!--                    app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"-->
    <!--                    app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"-->
    <!--                    app:mrl_rippleHover="true"-->
    <!--                    app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">-->
    
    <!--                    <ImageView-->
    <!--                        android:id="@+id/img_arrow_category3"-->
    <!--                        android:layout_width="24dp"-->
    <!--                        android:layout_height="24dp" />-->
    
    <!--                </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>-->
    
    <!--            </RelativeLayout>-->
    
    <!--        </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>-->
    
    <!--        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView-->
    <!--            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_category3"-->
    <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"-->
    <!--            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"-->
    <!--            android:scrollbars="none"-->
    <!--            android:scrollingCache="true" />-->
    
    <!--    </LinearLayout>-->
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                android:id="@+id/ripple_more_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp">
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/arrow_more"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_more"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
    
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_title_category"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    </LinearLayout>
    
                    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                        android:id="@+id/arrow_more"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                        app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_arrow_category"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" />
    
                    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
                </RelativeLayout>
    
            </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:scrollingCache="true" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <com.solodroid.ads.sdk.ui.MediumNativeAdView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_recipes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                android:id="@+id/ripple_recent_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp">
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/arrow_recent_more"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_recent_more"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
    
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_title_recent"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    </LinearLayout>
    
                    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                        android:id="@+id/arrow_recent_more"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                        app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_arrow_recent"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" />
    
                    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
                </RelativeLayout>
    
            </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_recent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:scrollingCache="true" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_videos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                android:id="@+id/ripple_videos_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp">
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/arrow_videos_more"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_videos_more"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
    
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_title_videos"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                    </LinearLayout>
    
                    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                        android:id="@+id/arrow_videos_more"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
                        app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
                        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
    
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_arrow_videos"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp" />
    
                    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
                </RelativeLayout>
    
            </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_videos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:scrollingCache="true" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: solved or not?..