# how decreasing recyleview card size is Shows me too much space. Need to reduce this

Tags: java, android

recyleview card size is decreasing how to reduce this. I have given the image below, look at it and predict. I should not have space.this card layout recyleview size decrease.I tried many times but I could not reduce the size this long size  i am new android devloper how to decreasing space card view
[image]

````
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="cards main container">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:tag="image_tag"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Android Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewVersion"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                    android:text="Android Version"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>



```
`

how to decreasing space card view
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="cards main container">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:tag="image_tag"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Android Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewVersion"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                    android:text="Android Version"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: clear this question bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74840791/how-to-increase-layout-rtlviewpager

Comment: this is your answer which i have edited just copy and paste this it will work.

Comment: working perfet  bro super

Comment: tell me quswer bro 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74840791/how-to-increase-layout-rtlviewpager

Comment: you have to wrap parent layout height.

Comment: adapterheader
 totel 8 text only show 3 text viewpager why bro

Comment: send screenshot and code..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ojFQnEC6sqPZ0wnTyKfKSmO3cOuJ-d0A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250525/discussion-between-jayaraman-jay-and-dhruv-sakariya).